# College Economics Student in Support of Crypto Looking for Live Hashrate Data

Tags: hash, hashpower, raw-data, live-data

I am a college economics student doing a Thesis project in support of the long term viability of Crypto. Does anyone know where I can get live Hashrate data for free or for sale? I appreciate it - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can get a current estimate of this info by running the bitcoin-core full node software and calling the command:

`bitcoin-cli getnetworkhashps`